# Why does a balance of payment deficit lead to an outflow of gold under a pre-WW1 gold standard?

Tags: monetary-policy, money-supply, gold-standard

I am trying to understand how gold flows "out" of the country during a BOP deficit and why this results in a contraction of the domestic money supply. I am not sure if the following explanation is correct:

If BOP<0, a current account deficit is insufficiently supported by private lending and would have to be financed via citizens exchanging domestic currency for gold from their domestic central bank. This gold would in turn be used by its citizens to purchase foreign currency from foreign central banks in order to import foreign goods.

The end result would be a movement of gold reserves from domestic to foreign central banks, a contraction of the domestic money supply (because citizens exchanged domestic currency for gold, thereby reducing the amount of domestic currency in circulation), and an expansion of the foreign money supply.

Is this explanation correct? Further, according to the "rules of the game" by Keynes, countries under a BOP deficit often sold domestic assets, contracted the money supply, and raised discount rates to reduce the outflow of gold. Why and how did this work in reducing the BOP deficit?

If these domestic assets were sold in exchange for cash, and no exchange of gold takes place, then wouldn't the subsequent reduction in domestic money supply decrease the price of gold in terms of domestic currency thereby violating the agreement to keep a fixed domestic price of gold?

Comment: Why do you think that explanation might be incorrect?

Comment: And how can the price of gold decrease if the government can always sell you some for a fixed price?